# Fix for excessive saliva/mucous during workouts?

Tags: breathing

I'd like to get in better shape, but I'm running into an unusual block (from what I can tell).  Whenever I try to work out - say on an exercise bike - after 5-10 minutes I have to stop and spend a few minutes clearing out my mouth and throat.  Saliva/mucous will literally build up to the point where I will start choking on it.  It's thick enough that I can't just swallow during the workout, that just makes the issue happen earlier as it triggers my gag reflex.  I can then resume, but I have to stop every couple of minutes after that to re-clear things.  Generally after about ~20 minutes, everything is clear enough that I can continue as normal.  However this is enough of a block that it usually keeps me from even trying to work out, since that "clearing out" process is very unpleasant.

I play hockey 1/week, and this also happens during that which causes issues with playing (it's actually started happening *before I leave* for hockey recently, which I'm assuming is a psychosomatic reaction of some sort).

I am not sure what could be causing this - whether it's disease, diet-related, or other - so my question is: **Has anyone else had a similar issue, or heard of it, and know what worked to fix the problem?**

Background info:
Male, early 30s, 225 lbs/6' tall.
Diet is poor, but I had a similar diet when I was a kid, played hockey then and had no issues like this.

Comment: Yeah I'd see a doctor about that.

Answer (score -2):

It could be some issue with the liquid balance part of your homeostasis.  Try drinking water before the workout or a little sip when you feel this happening. 
If nothing changes you should probably go see a doctor right away

Comment: Please don't use terms that you don't fully understand, or if you do, explain what the issue might be. "could be some issue" is so vague that it is meaningless.